# Why do I need to define queue name while creating microservice?

Tags: rabbitmq, microservices, nestjs

I want to have a hybrid NestJS app, HTTP + RabbitMQ. But don't get if I should create different microservices for each queue.

I have followed NestJS' RabbitMQ guide (https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/rabbitmq) and GitHub example (https://github.com/nestjs/nest/tree/master/sample/03-microservices).

**main.ts**

```js
app.connectMicroservice({
    transport: Transport.RMQ,
    options: {
      urls: [`amqp://user:user@hostname:5672`],
      queue: "cats_queue",
      queueOptions: { durable: false },
      prefetchCount: 1,
    }
  });
...
await app.startAllMicroservicesAsync();
```

**app.module.ts** (module import)

```
ClientsModule.register([{
      name: "CATS_QUEUE", transport: Transport.RMQ, options: {
        urls: [`amqp://user:user@hostname:5672`],
        queue: "cats_queue",
        queueOptions: { durable: false },
        prefetchCount: 1
      }
    }])
```

**app.controller.ts**

```
constructor(
    @Inject("CATS_QUEUE") private readonly client: ClientProxy
  ) {
  }
  @Get("mq")
  mq(): Observable<number> {
    const pattern = { cmd: "sum" };
    const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    return this.client.send<number>(pattern, data);
  }

  @MessagePattern({ cmd: "sum" })
  sum(data: number[]): number {
    console.log("MESSAGE RECEIVED : " + data.toString());
    return (data || []).reduce((a, b) => a + b);
  }
```

As I understood, I need to define `ClientsModule.register()` for each queue in `app.module.ts`. But why I also need to define RabbitMQ queue name while creating microservice? Do I need to create different microservices for each queue?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a NestJS user, but it seems logical that when you use queues to send messages between your microservices, you will need a queue for each microservice (not the other way around).

Queues are used to send (TO) and receive(Process) messages between independent components asynchronously.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. Yes, it does make sense, but what is the point to define queue name (and other queue options) in two different places (while registering client on app.module.ts and while creating the microservice on main.ts)?

Comment: My guess is that they are two different processes, Client (would have it's one queue defined) and probably somewhere define the microservice queue and vice versa.
Let me look at the actual sample code and get back to you :-)

Comment: So it would be possible to consume/produce messages. As from what I see, you are not able to consume messages without defining it in main.ts